# Trying to add a Custom CPQ Quote Field to Product Rule Error Condition

Tags: cpq

I'm trying to add a Custom Field in the Quote object to be used in the Tested Field of an Error Condition on a Product Rule in CPQ.

I've added the Custom Field to the Quote Object. Added the field to the Tested Field in the Error Condition object pick list. 
[image: Tested Field values]

But it does not show up in the Tested Field of the Error Condition.
[image: Tested Field in Error Condition]

I have tried to add existing Quote Object fields as well with the same result.

Am I missing a step here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested field on the Error Condition object is a [dependant picklist](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_using_the_field_dependency_matrix.htm&type=5) for Tested object Field(Look at the field above the Tested field in your screenshot). You will have to ensure that the new value you added to the tested field is select for the Quote Object field dependency.

For steps to enable field dependency:

1. Lightning Setup
2. Object Manager
3. Error Condition
4. Fields & Relationships
5. On the top right you a button for Field Dependencies
6. Make sure you selected your new picklist value for Quote Object dependency.

This should enable the picklist for selection when you go back to your error condtion.